# accessing this.Master.Master.findcontrol()

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, master-pages

I am trying to access the Master page that is Master of the page's Master. I am using the following syntax to do it..

```
                this.Master.Master.FindControl("abc");
```

however this generates the following error.

```
        The type 'ASP.masterpage_master' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'App_Web_masterpage.master.cdcab7d2.fhyd3fxv, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

I have included the at mastertype attribute properly on each nested master page.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/900352.aspx/1

Comment: Hi! this forum itself shows question only there is no answer given..